# Hello, how to force show default parameters in te URL in a route

Tags: symfony, parameters, routes, annotations, documentation

I'm starting symfony and I have this situation.

I read in the documentation:

https://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_getting_started_4.3.pdf

PAGE 21

That it is possible in an annotation path to force the URL to include the default parameter of the matching method, as I read just put the character **!** before the parameter name: / blog / {!page}

I have the following code where I am looking to test this feature (taken from the Symfony documentation)

> ```
> // src/Controller/BlogController.php
> namespace App\Controller;
> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 
> use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route; 
>
> class BlogController  
> {
>       /**
>       * @Route("/blog/{page}", name="blog_list")
>       */
>       public function list(int $page = 1)
>       {
>           return new Response( 
>              '<html></body>Lucky number: '.$page.'</body></html>'
>           );
>       }
>
> }
> ```

This code works fine if i write in my browser

> http://localhost/index.php/blog

But when I try to force the URL to show the default value by doing exactly what the documentation mentions, putting "!" before the name of the parameter in the route {! page} being as follows:

> /**
>      * @Route("/blog/{!page}", name="blog_list")
>      */

It shows the following error:

> No route found for "GET /blog"

I don't know if I'm reading the documentation badly but I can't find what I'm doing wrong, I appreciate any help.

Comment: Consider updating your question with a link to the docs you are referencing.  I'm too lazy to look it up myself.

Comment: Are you using Symfony 4.3?

Comment: Hello Cerad, yes I'm using Symfony 4.3.5

Comment: I'm getting the same 'no route found' on a fresh project.  Tried a few things but could not get around it.  Did not find any related issues on github.  Maybe someone else has the answer.  Or maybe try on the Symfony slack channel.

Answer (score 0):

As read in the [documentation of optional parameters](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#optional-parameters), ... default values can be inlined in each parameter using the syntax {parameter_name?default_value}.

```
// src/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class BlogController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog/{page<\d+>?1}", name="blog_list")
     */
    public function list(int $page)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To give a null default value to any parameter, add nothing after the ? character (e.g. /blog/{page?}).

Comment: The question is about using !page which will cause urls to always be generated with a page parameter.  The docs are somewhat misleading.  Adding the ! causes /blog to generate a route not found error.

Comment: Ok, ... "for example to force the generation of /blog/1 instead of /blog in the previous example" means that "/blog" cant exists. I think.

Comment: Not according to [the docs](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-3-always-include-route-default-values).  The ! operator supposedly applies to url generation, not actual routing.  But the docs are confusing to say the least.  In any event, since your answer does not include the ! then it seems to be irrelevant to the question.